# Have problem with static varible in java, can't add element on ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm trying to add, delete and edit the Slang (for example the key is: 3, it has a value of cute).

I have to use Java Swing. I have to use Java extra Swing. Because working with many classes at the same time, the variable that stores the `[key, value]` I set the variable static.

`private static Map<String, ArrayList<String>> multiMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();`

I have the operation that is adding 1 data slang. If it matches, it will add value to the existing slang.
I noticed, if you add a slang, it means adding a pair of `[key, value]`, then when you find that pair of `[key, value]`, you will find it. When adding value to the existing slang, I could not find it.

I'm guessing that since `multiMap` is `static` and `ArrayList` is not static if we only change the value of ArrayList, when accessed elsewhere it will not be updated. So in case of entering the same key, I choose to delete the old key and add a new one.

```java
String[] valueStrings = null;

if(value.length() > 0){
        valueStrings = value.split("[|]");
        for(int i = 0; i <valueStrings.length; i++){
            valueStrings[i] = valueStrings[i].trim();

        }
    }
if(choose == 0){ // 0 it mean new
    Slang.multiMap.put(NewSlangs, new ArrayList<>());
    Slang.multiMap.get(NewSlangs).addAll(Arrays.asList(valueStrings));
}
else if(choose == 2){ // 2 it mean old
    ArrayList<String> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    tempArrayList.addAll(multiMap.get(NewSlangs));
    tempArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(valueStrings));
    Slang.multiMap.remove(NewSlangs); 
    Slang.multiMap.put(NewSlangs, tempArrayList);
}
```

After an error is added to the new key, value, when looking again, it will be found. But not with inserting value. So I debug and have some problems here.

[When adding new Array List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/950GA.png)

The new `ArrayList` address I added is`# 1893` and I found it using the search function

[When adding value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxbpm.png)
[, error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEVRQ.png)

The old `ArrayList` contains old values with the address `# 2050`

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzjnT.png)
The new `ArrayList` contains new values whose address is `# 2088`

But when looking for it, it only contains the old 4 values
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckjBO.png)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpeYc.png)
and its address is also different.

So I am asking why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be unnecessarily complex. I suggest simplifying it and then coming up with a simple example that demonstrates the problem you are having. A simple implementation of a multi-map would look like:

```
for (String strValue: value.split("|")) {
    multimap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(strValue.trim());
}
```

There is no need to create temporary lists nor to remove a map entry before adding a new value for the same key.